# Is there a theorem in Differential Geometry for surfaces can be deformed without stretching?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, mean-curvature-flows

I'm an amateur mathematician who is keen on self-studying DG. I want to know if there is a theorem in DG that proves that surfaces can be "continuously deformed" without stretching, from one surface to another, without changing the intrinsic geometry? Is "continuous deformation without stretching" possible for any arbitrary surface? If not, what intrinsic property of a surface dictates that it is not possible?

Comment: Are you asking about surfaces isometrically embedded in $\Bbb R^3$? (Presumably yes, since this is the typical setting of these problems.) Some results along these lines depend on the regularity of the embeddings of the surfaces---do you have a particular regularity in mind?

Comment: See [Theorema Egregium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium)

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a deformation through isometries. One of the classic beautiful examples of such a phenomenon is the isometric deformation of a helicoid to a catenoid. What's more, these are minimal surfaces, as are all the intermediate surfaces.

Comment: So just to give a bit of background to why I posted: I'm currently reading a textbook called "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristan Needham. In one of the chapters, he gives the following analogy - "Take a ping-pong ball and cut it in half: as you gently flex one of the hemispheres, you obtain infinitely many surfaces whose intrinsic geometry is identical to that of the original sphere". Is this true? I'm struggling to grasp how it is. Although I am thinking about it from a "material" sense. It seems to me that the material would be under compression when distorting the ball.

Comment: @MSobak Thanks for the link! After having read the overview of Theorema Egregium, it seems that "distorting the surface without stretching it" is actually a pre-requisite for an invariance in Gaussian curvature. However, how can one establish whether or not a surface can actually be distorted in such a manner? What is the intrinsic property of the surface that dictates whether it can be distorted without stretching?

Comment: The keyword here is *rigidity*. For example, Cohn-Vossen proved that the only (global) isometry between two closed convex (positively-curved) surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ is a rigid motion. That is, a closed convex surface is *rigid* (cannot be deformed). I haven't perused it too carefully, but [this article](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/Geschichte/COHN-VOSSEN,Stefan/Alexandrov_Iacob.pdf) might be interesting to you.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah okay, I see. So if you have a hemisphere, which is not closed, then it is no longer rigid, and therefore is isometric to infinitely many surfaces. Am I right?

Comment: In fact, there are lots of (non-closed) surfaces with constant curvature $1$ other that a sphere, but the sphere is the only *compact* one.  You can write down the differential equation to get all the surfaces of revolution (and, not surprisingly, elliptic integrals show up) — these form a nice continuous 1-parameter family.